# MVC DropDownListFor variable type issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist, dropdownlistfor

Here is my problem :

I'm working on a MVC internet application and I try to manage users. First of all, my Edit view show the username and the role of the selected user. The roles that can choose the user are listed in a DropDownListFor in my HTML view. When I clicked "Edit this user", an error occur showing me :

The ViewData element with the key « RoleId » is type « System.Int32 » but needs to be and « IEnumerable ».

Here is my view Model:

```
using GestionStages.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc; >

> namespace GestionStages.Areas.Stages.ViewModels
{
    public class UserRoleViewModel
    {
        public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }
        public SelectList Roles { get; set; }
        public UserProfile User { get; set; }
        public String CurrentUserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A role is required")]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is a part of my HTML Edit view :

```
<div class="form_row">
     @Html.Label("Roles")
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RoleId,  Model.Roles)
</div>
```

Here is my edit methods in my controller :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    UserRoleViewModel model = new UserRoleViewModel();
    model.User = db.UserProfiles.Find(id);

    if (model.User == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    model.Roles = new SelectList(db.webpages_Roles.ToList(), "RoleId", "RoleName");
    model.CurrentUserName = model.User.UserName;
    model.RoleId = model.User.webpages_Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId;

    return View(model);
}

//
// POST: /Sales/Sale/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserRoleViewModel model)
{
    if ((model.User.UserName != model.CurrentUserName && db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName == model.User.UserName).Any()))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user is already in the database");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(model.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Thanks for the help